# Does the 5-hyperrectangle break any complexity thresholds analogous to quintics?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, p-adic-number-theory, quintics

A function similar to Minkowski's question-mark [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function) pairs periodic 2-adic numbers with quadratic irrationals, and pairs these with rectangle-shapes.

It is likely that periodic 5-adic numbers can be paired with quintics and with 5-hyperrectangles.

Are the 5-hyperrectangles known to break some complexity threshold akin to the Abel-Ruffini [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)?